# Collections.synchonizedMap and synchronization

Tags: java, collections

From javadocs

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
      ...
  Set s = m.keySet();  // Needn't be in synchronized block
      ...
  synchronized(m) {  // Synchronizing on m, not s!
      Iterator i = s.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
      while (i.hasNext())
          foo(i.next());
  }
```

Here Why iterator has been enclosed in synchronized block?

Does this mean everytime we need to iterate over synchronizedMap we have to enclose iterator in synchronized block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `synchronizedMap` does is that it guarantees that the (atomic) operations executed on the map `m` will be synchronized, for instance

```
m.put('somekey', object);
```

Therefore if you run an operation which requires more steps to complete, for instance

1. read a value
2. if  != null delete

that should be in synchronized block.

Regarding the above example, the function `foo` may remove or add new elements to the `Map m`, which will be synchronized, yes, but other threads in the same time may read from the map.

Imagine that there is no synchronized:

1. thread 1 calls `i.hasNext()` which returned true
2. thread 2 calls `foo` which removed the last element from the map
3. thread 1 calls `i.next()` <- exception, the map is empty